# How to concatenate attributes in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show the following attributes as a comma separated list in html:

```
json {
    "city":"<b>londo</b>",
    "country":"<i>uk</i>",
    "zip":"123"
}
```

As I have to render the html markup, I'm using `ngSanitize`. Also I have to apply a filter on each element.

If only one element would be shown, I'd write:

```
<h3 ng-bind-html="data.country | touppercase"></h3>
```

But how can I create a oneline comma separated list? How can I append just the three attributes in the h3?
If I'd just use three `h3` tags one after the other, I'd have linebreaks between them. So what else could I do?

Comment: Probably easier to do in the controller code, `$scope.joined = Object.keys(json).map(function(key) { return json[key] }).join(",");`

Comment: Yes but I'd like to avoid a controller mapping here, I'm just looking for a html way to concatenate them.

Comment: You could make a `$scope` method that returns the joined list, and then use `ng-bind-html="getJoinedList(data.country) | touppercase"`

Comment: You can resolve it with CSS (I recomend you use ul and li instead h3) check that: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm

Comment: @tymeJV and how could I feed the `getJoinedList` with the different attributes?

Comment: Are those attributes defined anywhere?

Comment: The attributes are defined by json input, and thus contained in the `data` property.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes and filters can be concatenated directly withint the angularjs tags:

```
<h3 ng-bind-html="(data.country | touppercase) + ', ' + (data.city | touppercase) + ', ' + (data.zip)"></h3>
```